# VB.Net - Write plain text to .txt, keep carriage returns

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a form where I load .txt files into a RichTextBox. An event triggers:

```
rtxtSONotes.LoadFile(stTextLink, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

I want the ability to add to the text and then just replace the old file with the contents of the RichTextBox with a button:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(stTextLink, rtxtSONotes.Text, False)
```

This actually works great if I stay within the form, it displays exactly how I told it to look in my RichTextBox, meaning all new lines/carriage returns are there. However, if I open the actual .txt file in Notepad then everything is boiled down to one continuous line and is unreadable for most users. I don't want the form to be the only way users can read the file.

Is there a way to preserve carriage returns when writing from a form to a .txt file? I would prefer to keep the files as .txt if possible, rather than something like .rtf.

Comment: So, what does this have to do with VBA?

Comment: I assume this is a coding issue for what I'm sending to the .txt file, or at least that's what I'm using to communicate with the .txt file.

Comment: Slai explained that I was lumping my VBA and VB.Net terms together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(stTextLink, rtxtSONotes.Lines)
```

Comment: It tells me "'WriteAllLines' is not a member of 'Microsoft. VisualBasic.MyServices.FileSystemProxy'."

Comment: @Pursuit my bad, I was lazy and didn't check the documentation. Updated. BTW, VBA is for Microsoft Office automation and is different than the VB.Net in Visual Studio.

Comment: I really appreciate the clarification on VBA/VB.Net, that's nothing I paid attention to before and it will help a ton when searching for help in the future. And you got my answer right on, double thanks!